# App getting hang and crash while loading thousands of marker, Please help to get this fix

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-maps-markers

After updating google map to 18.0.2, map screen getting hanged and crash with ANR while loading thousands of marker cluster on map.

Basically, What's happening is, an api is get call every time when map is scrolled by the user. Then in api response, I'm getting list of restaurants with all the details like lat/lng points, name, title etc. and then call goes to addItem()method which updates the clusterMapList with the restaurant details in a thread and then clusterManager.addItems() is get called on the main thread to add the markers on google map. Then pre setup cluster manager shows the markers and the markers used are the custom markers (.png) from drawables.

Here's the code snippet

```
private void addItem() {
try {
    if (thread != null) {
        if (thread.isAlive()) {
            thread.interrupt();
        }

        clusterMapList.clear();
        clusterManager.clearItems();
    }

    if (restaurantListMap != null) {

        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (RestaurantDatum obj: restaurantListMap) {
                    clusterMapList.add(new clusterMapList(
                        Double.parseDouble(obj.getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(obj.getLongitude()), obj.getRestaurantName(), obj.getCity() + ", " + obj.getState(), obj.getCategory(), obj.getRestaurantId(), obj.getImageUrl()

                    ));

                } //for each

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        clusterManager.addItems(clusterMapList);
                        clusterManager.cluster();

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        thread.start();

    } //if

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

} //addItem

```
private void setUpClusterManager(GoogleMap googleMap) {
clusterManager = new ClusterManager < > (this, googleMap);
clusterManager.setRenderer(new DefaultClusterRenderer < clusterMapList > (this, googleMap, clusterManager) {
    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(@NonNull clusterMapList item, @NonNull MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker_gf_small_1);
        markerOptions.icon(bitmapDescriptor);
        super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClusterItemRendered(@NonNull com.glutendudeapp.ui.letseat.clusterMapList clusterItem, @NonNull Marker marker) {
        if (clusterItem.getCategory().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            try {
                marker.setIcon(bitmapDescriptorGF);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            try {
                marker.setIcon(bitmapDescriptorCC);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        marker.setTag(clusterItem.getImageUrl() + "");

        super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker);

    } //onClusterItemRendered

    @Override
    protected void onClusterRendered(@NonNull Cluster < clusterMapList > cluster, @NonNull Marker marker) {
        super.onClusterRendered(cluster, marker);

    } //onClusterRendered
});

clusterManager.getMarkerCollection().setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(@NonNull Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(@NonNull Marker marker) {
        windlowInfoClicked = true;
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_custom_infowindow, null);

        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgRest);
        ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.bar);
        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title_map);
        TextView tvSnippet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.snippet_map);

        tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());

        String snip = marker.getSnippet();
        tvSnippet.setText(snip);

        try {
            Address addr = Utility.getAddress(LetsEatActivity.this, marker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude);
            String addrr = addr.getAddressLine(0);
            tvSnippet.setText(addrr);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Picasso.with(LetsEatActivity.this).load(String.valueOf(marker.getTag()))
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_7_day_trial)
            .into(img, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                    try {
                        if (marker != null && marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
                            marker.hideInfoWindow();
                            marker.showInfoWindow();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } //onSuccess

                @Override
                public void onError() {

                }
            });

        return v;

    } //getInfoWindow
});

clusterManager.setOnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener < clusterMapList > () {
    @Override
    public void onClusterItemInfoWindowClick(clusterMapList item) {

        Intent In = new Intent(LetsEatActivity.this, ActivityRestaurantDetails.class);
        restaurandId = String.valueOf(item.getRestaurantId());
        In.putExtra("restaurantId", restaurandId);
        Log.e("infoWindow", restaurandId);
        if (currentLocation != null) {
            In.putExtra("CURRENT_LATITUDE", String.valueOf(currentLocation.getLatitude()));
            In.putExtra("CURRENT_LONGITUDE", String.valueOf(currentLocation.getLongitude()));
        } else {
            In.putExtra("CURRENT_LATITUDE", "");
            In.putExtra("CURRENT_LONGITUDE", "");
        }
        startActivity(In);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    }
});

addItem();
```

} //setUpClusterManager

Here below is the drive link of the screen recording of the app, kindly please check.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CnWvCyWi4JD6h5NhvJJwmad6zZahH_uM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: give us Stack or snippet pls? are you doing this in the main thread?

Comment: @Fabrizio Scarponi
Hi, thank you for the response, I have updated the post with the code snippets, kindly please check. preparing clusterMapList in another thread and then clusterManager adding clusterMapList items on main thread.

Comment: @Fabrizio Scarponi
actually the same code was working fine before updating the google map dependency, but after updating the library to 18.0.2 it's unable to work smoothly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ty, now I'll take a look, but I need some time cause I'm at work

Comment: If you were in kotlin coroutines probably would solve your problem, but I'm almost sure that your app is performing too much work on the main thread.
It would help if you implement a way to reduce the number of markers on map based on zoom level. 
Take a look at how google maps work, zoom out and search for a pharmacy is show only the nearest markers... another way is to create a "grouped marker" when u zoom out and perform a redrawing on map when you zoom in (see how booking.com works)

Comment: @FabrizioScarponi Hi, thank you again for the response and suggestions, but this time, luckily I was able to find the cause which was making app hang and crash with ANR. I have put a lot of logs on all the methods etc and checked the logcat and found the culprit, it is getInfoMethod which is blocking the main thread. Actually what's happening is it all works fine until user click on a marker to view the info window, as soon as he clicks on it, this method goes in loop calling again and again itself i.e recursion occurs and it make app hang and then crash.

Comment: actually what's happening here is in info window, there is an image along with other details of the restaurant, previously when user was clicking on an marker then first time image was not getting shown on info window

Comment: but when he click on the same marker second time, the image get shown, now for this, a workaround was done in code like hiding infowindow and then loading it again in order to show the image. This workaround was working fine before updating the google maps lib but now its creating problem don't know why. so looking workaround for this, also I have tested commenting this workaround and it worked fine after this. but still that not good as user will not see image first time :(

Comment: Now problem occurring is that info windows not getting clear

Comment: done fixed, issue was related with showing image from url into info window, finally improved code related with info window and all working fine now, helping link -> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows 
key point is just show the info window after loading the image and getting success callback.